# How do I get the old user-based login screen to work in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login, lts, desktop-background

I remember back in the day if I had 3 accounts on my Ubuntu system and each had a different wallpaper I would see each wallpaper at the login screen (depending on which account was selected). Now in 18.04 I don't get that by default. As an added complication I run xplanet and it changes my wallpaper every 20 minutes.

How do I get the login screen to show my desktop wallpaper when my account is selected.

P.S. I checked many other "solutions" and they were either not for 18.04 or just plain didn't work. Also I recently installed 18.04 from a thumb drive (it's sparkly new).

Also I don't think I have gdm. I got this response from dpkg-reconfigure:
    /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: gdm is not installed
Also: $ps ax  gives me this output 
958 tty1     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart
I've installed lightdm, but all that did was get me the orange beaver background back.

Update: It seems there may be a security issue involved in having access to an account's walpaper before login. It seems this may have been blocked  due to a security hole.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have `lightdm` installed, then a terminal enter

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

And select the `lightdm` option from the ncurses menu then restart. After changing your background, the login screen should now show the new background.

If you don't have `lightdm` installed you can install it with

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

Comment: I don't think I have gdm. I got this response:
    /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: gdm is not installed

Comment: What happens if you try gdm3 instead?

Comment: installing lightdm... I think this will do it.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong about my assumption that if you upgraded from 16.04 you'd still have lightdm installed. (I'm still running 16.04 so I can't verify on my system). What is the output of  'dpkg -l lightdm' ?

Comment: Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold                                                          
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend                       
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)                                            
||/ Name                        Version            Architecture       Description                     
ii  lightdm                     1.26.0-0ubuntu1    amd64              Display Manager

Comment: I got the default "beaver" back. So there's that.

Comment: So lightdm is installed at this point. Are you getting the lightdm login screen or the Gnome one? I wouldn't be surprised if the desktop background in lightdm defaulted to the beaver, but now if you change your desktop background and reboot you should get a login screen with your chosen background.

Comment: Nope. xplanet is my wallpaper and I still get the beaver.

Comment: Did lightdm previously pick up on the backgrounds set by xplanet? What happens if you change the wallpaper from going to system settings -> appearance ?